# mmap in C for textfiles

Tags: c, mmap

Is it possible to use mmap in C for reading textfiles ? I know its possible with binary files. But when I try to read an entire textfile I seem to be having some problems.

Comment: What kind of problems are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that works of course - "text files" are just a subset of "binary files" anyway.

However, don't expect a trailing `\0` so you cannot use any string functions since they require NUL-terminated strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mmap on any file.

You should elaborate on your problems.